# Good application for printing envelopes?

Tags: openoffice.org, software-recommendation

Does Evolution have the ability to print envelopes for your contacts? How about one of the OpenOffice applications?

I'm going to be setting up an Ubuntu PC for my parents company soon and was wondering which applications you guys would recommend for business contact managing and envelope printing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

**OpenOffice.org** does envelopes [quite excellently](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Printing_envelopes).

Open any text document, click on Insert → Envelope. The rest is completely self-explanatory to anybody who's ever had to use office-type software.

Comment: Where does it pull these contacts from? Are they specifically saved in OO or are they the Evolution contacts or what?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but from the looks of the UI, the contacts can be pulled from every application that is properly integrated (in technical terms, provides OOo with a database it knows about). Evolution is in fact one of them. It can use those databases to just paste an addressee, or serialise and automate the whole process. In short, yes, it knows about Evolution's contacts. In my example, I just made it up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it will be *exactly* what you want, but give [glabels](http://apt://glabels) a try.

[image]

I believe it has optional integration with other programs (possibly evolution). I use it for business cards, but envelope templates are in there too.

If you want undo/redo functionality though, you will need to get the development version from the [website](http://www.glabels.org/) and compile it (`sudo make checkinstall` **as opposed to** `sudo make install` for the last step).